# Adding elements to d3 graph without removal

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to add circles to an svg plot as a basic visualisation of an array. However the only way I've managed to retain the "old" array data, when adding in newData is the have an array maintained outside of the update function.

I'm fairly sure this is bad d3-wise, but I couldn't figure out how to keep the old array elements, while adding new ones. I want the circles to be in the order that they're added.

Here's the working code I have, that uses the outside 'data' array.

```
var data = [];

function update(newData) {
  data.push(newData);

  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data, function(d, i){ return i;});

  console.log(circle.data());

  circle.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d); })
    .attr("cy", 250);

  circle.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return x(i); });
}
```

When I don't have the data array, and pass the newData array into the code like this:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(newData, function(d, i){ return i;});
```

It seems to remove all existing elements of the data. Any help to improve my code is much appreciated.

Comment: D3 matches data to DOM elements by index by default. You probably want to match based on the data itself, e.g. an ID or something like that, so `data(newData, function(d) { return d.id; })`.

Comment: I should add that the data is just a plain array of integers [500, 250, 600] etc. I don't really want it to "match" existing data at all, just add it nonetheless.

Comment: So then `.data(newData, function(d) { return d; })`.

Comment: Would that prevent two of the same number being added?

Comment: Yes. If you want to simply add all data regardless of whether it's there or not, you don't need to use D3's update pattern.